# Insert JQuery in a zul file

Tags: jquery-plugins, zk

Hello I'm working on a project using ZK. What I need to do is passing a value from a label to a JQuery function to do a countdown.

I need to use this plugin : www.jqueryscript.net/loading/Graphical-Circular-Timer-with-jQuery-CSS3-pietimer.html

I have tried to insert this plugin in zul page but is doesn't seem to work.

I'm kinda of new in JQuery, I didn't know how to pass a value to "timerSeconds" from a label .

Here what I have tried to do so far :

```
<?link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/top.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"?>
<?link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pietimer.css"?>

<zk>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.pietimer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="true">
<![CDATA[
    jq(function() {
        zk('#timer').pietimer({
          timerSeconds: 60,// i need to insert a label value instand of 60
          color: '#234',
          fill: false,
          showPercentage: true,
          callback: function() {

          }
      });
    });
    ]]>
  </script>
  <div id="timer" style="margin-top:100px;"></div>

</zk>
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that *jq()* and *zk()* are the ZK own scope, but *pietimer()* is added below another *jQuery* version, so I guess you may use this to solve it.

```
zk.afterMount(function () { // run when ZK widgets are ready
  $('#timer').pietimer({ // use $ instead of zk or jq
      timerSeconds: 60,// i need to insert a label value instand of 60
      color: '#234',
      fill: false,
      showPercentage: true,
      callback: function() {

      }
 });
});
```